# iOS Localizable string Arabic formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c, format

I have trouble formatting arabic letters. In my `Localizable.strings` I have, in English, for example: `"Rating: %.1f"`. Every time when I want to write that in Arabic when I write a number it goes like this: `"تصنيف: %.1f"`. Can somebody help me, how to properly format text with decimal numbers in Arabic?

Comment: Could you please show us the code where you create an output in Arabic?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

NSNumberFormatter -setMaximumFractionDigits: is used for that purpose and you can reuse the formatter which is quite good:

```js
NSNumberFormatter * formatter =  [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString * myString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:123.456]];
```